# Vosk Python Русский и Английский одновременно

Tags: python, python-3.x

Подскажите, как можно подключить русскую и английскую модель в библиотеку offline распознавания речи vosk на языке Python для распознавания русского и английского языка в одной фразе. Результат распознавания должен выглядеть как-то так:

```
hello в английском языке означает приветствие
```

Ссылка на документацию библиотеки: https://alphacephei.com/vosk/

Comment: Такой же вопрос, нашел решение?

Answer (score 0):

У Vosk есть модель для распознавания языка, Speaker Identification Model, поищите на их сайте в разделе модели, должно помочь

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Скорей всего придется модифицировать модель (см. пример https://habr.com/ru/articles/735480/): добавлять к русской модели английские слова, либо наоборот к английской модели добавлять русские слова.

То что вам ранее посоветовали: "Model for speaker identification, should work for all languages" (vosk-model-spk-0.4) эта модель совсем для других целей. Эта модель нужна для того что-бы идентифицировать говорящего: у каждого голоса есть свои особенности, которые модель преобразует в массив чисел ("идентификационный слепок голоса").

Пример того как идентифицировать голос: https://github.com/virex-84/VoskIdentification.